# Alternating end and start value of groups Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a df ('c' always starts with 0 and 'y' always starts with 1 in each group):

```
a  b  c  d
0  1  0  1
0  1  0  1
0  2  0  1
0  2  0  0
1  3  0  1
1  3  1  0
1  2  0  1
1  2  0  0
```

The groups (grouped by 'a' and 'b') in columns 'c' and 'd' are the alternatives to pick-
End value of each group should alternate with first of next group (transition between subgroups doesn't matter).
For the first group in a subgroup ('a') pick column 'c'.

Result should be:

```
a  b    c    d
0  1    0    nan
0  1    0    nan
0  2    nan  1
0  2    nan  0
1  3    0    nan
1  3    1    nan
1  2    0    nan
1  2    0    nan
```

Any ideas? Maybe sth like pick group in column c and if they are both 0, next group in c is nan nan.

Comment: just edited....

Comment: This is unclear to me.  Why are the last two records showing 'c' in stead of 'd'?

Comment: because the group before ended with 1. If it ends with 1, next group should start with 0 (column c)